# Installed mysql gem file and received error 'wrong number of arguments (4 for 0) (ArgumentError)'

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am trying to run the following ruby program

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'
db = Mysql.new('local','root','','')
st_qry = db.query("SELECT * FROM `notification` ORDER BY notification_id DESC ")
puts ("There were #{st_qry.num_rows} rows returned.")
```

When I execute this code through terminal I get the following error message:

```
joe.fleck$ ruby mysql_req.rb 
mysql_req.rb:4:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (4 for 0) (ArgumentError)
from mysql_req.rb:4:in `new'
from mysql_req.rb:4
```

I have no idea how to fix this.  I had to install mysql by this command:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- \
--with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib \
--with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

because the ordinary command (sudo gem install mysql) would error and not install.

I have also tried uninstall and install mysql.  I tried mysql2 and it errors out when I try to execute the program.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

MacBook Pro, OS X version 10.8.2

```
$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
addressable (2.3.2)
builder (3.1.3)
childprocess (0.3.5)
cucumber (1.2.1)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
ffi (1.1.5)
gherkin (2.11.3)
json (1.7.5)
libwebsocket (0.1.5)
multi_json (1.3.6)
mysql (2.8.1)
pkg-config (1.1.4)
rb-appscript (0.6.1)
rubygems-update (1.8.24)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
safariwatir (0.4.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.25.0)
shoes (3.0.1)
watir-webdriver (0.6.1)
```

Comment: do you really need to stick directly with gem? why wont you use a tool that does "underground" job for you? for example this one https://github.com/d11wtq/rdo

Comment: Hmm. The mysql gem was last updated in 2009. Perhaps you may want to try the [mysql2](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) gem?

Comment: @Jfleck Try Updating Mysql Gem since for me both mysql and mysql2 work with ease

Comment: I did try updating the mysql gem but the response is 'Nothing to update'.  I get an error when using mysql2 too.

Comment: Here is the error I get when trying to use mysql2.  `code`/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Comment: The version I am using is 1.8.7.